# C# .net read from .xls missing cell with content 1

Tags: c#, xls

I tried to read data from a xls file using oledb. The sheet had a column which has numbers in all the cells. When I executed the code that particular column alone is missing everytime. The code I used is:

```
OleDbConnection excel_connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + file_name + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");
        excel_connection.Open();
        DataSet excel_data = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [XX$]", excel_connection);
        myCommand.Fill(excel_data);
        excel_connection.Close();
        int index = 0;
        string excel_columns;
        foreach (DataRow excel_row in excel_data.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
                excel_columns = String.Join(",", cells);
                richTextBox1.AppendText(excel_columns);

        }
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to read Excel document like you do but I kept having problems with column formats so I decided to switch to [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/).
It is a good product and works pretty well. The implementation is very very easy.

Here is some code:

```
using (FileStream Xlfile = new FileStream(MyFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (HSSFWorkbook XLBook = new HSSFWorkbook(Xlfile))
    {
    using (NPOI.SS.UserModel.Sheet XLSheet = XLBook.GetSheetAt(0))
    {
        NPOI.HSSF.UserModel.HSSFRow CurrentRow;
        NPOI.SS.UserModel.Cell CurrentCell;

        IEnumerator RowEnum = XLSheet.GetRowEnumerator();

        while (RowEnum.MoveNext())
        {
        iLoopRows++;

        if (RowEnum.Current != null)
        {
            rowCounter++;
            CurrentRow = RowEnum.Current as NPOI.HSSF.UserModel.HSSFRow;

            for (Int32 iLoop = 0; iLoop < CurrentRow.Cells.Count; iLoop++)
            {
            CurrentCell = CurrentRow.Cells[iLoop];

            switch (CurrentCell.CellType)
            {
                case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.STRING:
                // Reading STRING value
                // CurrentCell.StringCellValue;
                break;
                case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.NUMERIC:
                // Reading NUMERIC and DATA VALUES
                // (CurrentCell.DateCellValue == null) ? "" : CurrentCell.DateCellValue.ToString();
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
    Xlfile.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But in my excel sheet I have all the column format to text. Still the problem is there. i will give a try of the method you have mentioned.

Comment: @Vicky: If you have the chance to publish your spreadsheet somewhere I can have a look at it. As I told you I have struggled quite a while with your system and then I gave up. NPOI can work with formulas and typed columns.

Comment: I did it using NPOI itself. Works great. Thanks a lot :)